# How to include additional feature columns in Databricks AutoML Forecast?

Tags: databricks, feature-selection, feature-engineering, automl

I'm using Databricks AutoML for time series forecasting, and I would like to include additional feature columns in my model to improve its performance. The available parameters in the **databricks.automl.forecast()** function primarily focus on the **target_col** and **time_col**. Although there is an **identity_col** parameter for multi-series forecasting, it doesn't seem to be intended for specifying additional feature columns directly.

Is there a way to make Databricks AutoML consider additional feature columns when training the forecasting model? If not, what are the best practices for incorporating additional features to enhance my time series forecast using Databricks AutoML? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

I tried building AUTOARIMA and Prophet models, which allowed me to include the feature columns, but it would be great if I could get Databricks AutoML working with these additional features.

Thank you!